# C: Best way to hide if-statement in macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

What is the best practice of hiding if-statement in `#define`?

1. You can use `if` in define:

```
#define MY_MACRO(isTrue) if(isTrue) do()
```

My intuition says that this is bad approach. Could you give an example, why it's so or why not? For example, anyone who use this can add `else` after macro.

2. You can use ternary operator:

```
#define MY_MACRO(isTrue) (isTrue) ? do() : do_not()
//OR
#define MY_MACRO(isTrue) (isTrue) ? do() : (void)0
```

Here I understand, why it's not good. For example, anyone can call your function `do()` with simple `true || MY_MACRO(?)`

3. My current solution for this issue is do-while-false

```
#define MY_MACRO(isTrue) do { if(isTrue) do(); } while (false)
```

Is this actually the best approach? What bad can happen with this macro?

Comment: Why do you need to overcomplicate it?

Comment: I assume `do()` is supposed to be a function and not use of the `do` keyword, right?

Comment: *What is the best practice of hiding if-statement in #define* - best practice is not to do it.

Comment: "anyone can call your function `do()` with " -> None of this stuff will prevent anyone from calling the `do()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1, it can't be used like this:

```
if (foo) MY_MACRO(bar);
else something_else();
```

Because that would be expanded like this:

```
if (foo) {
    if (isTrue) {
        do();
    } else {
        something_else();
    }
}
```

The `else` will (unexpectedly) be the `else` for the `if` inside the macro.

The bad thing about your current approach is it can't be used where a statement is needed (e.g. `f((MY_MACRO(a), b), c)` in a comma expression won't work), but since you use it for the side effects of `do()`, it wouldn't be used where a statement is required.

Since it seems quite short, you can make it act like a statement, just add another pair of brackets to fix your problem with 2:

```
#define MY_MACRO(isTrue) ((isTrue) ? do() : (void)0)
```

You should also want to consider a `static conditional_do(bool isTrue) { if (isTrue) { do(); } }` instead of a macro.